# How to train NN in batches with odd examples size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am a newbie in the NN field and I am doing some training with pytorch.
I decided to make a simple vanilla NN.
I used a personal dataset i had with 2377 numerical features and 6277 examples.

My first try was to make the NN predict each single example, so the pseudocode would look like

```
for i in range(...):
    X = ... # features
    y = ... # outcome
    y_pred = model(X[i])
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)

    y_pred.size # [1,1]
    y.size # [1,1]
```

This took about 10 seconds per epoch and i decided to improve it using mini batches.

So i define the batch size at the beginning and the NN in Pytorch is defined like this

```
batch_size = 30
n_inputs = X.size[1] #2377

## 2 hidden layers
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(n_inputs, 1024),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(1024, 512),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(512, 356),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(356, batch_size),
    nn.ReLU(),
)
```

And then I do the training in batches

```py
for epoch in range(5):
    totalloss = 0  
    permutation = torch.randperm(X.size()[0])
    for i in range(0, X.size()[0], batch_size):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        indices = permutation[i:i+batch_size]
        batch_x, batch_y = x[indices], y[indices]

        ypred = model(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(ypred, batch_y) 
        totalloss += loss.item()
        
        ## update the weights
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Now the problem is that my NN always outputs 100 values **but** the last batch size can vary.
In fact, if i choose 100 as batch size the last batch will be made of 77 examples (6277%100).

I am sure there is a way around this problem, and that there is a mistake in my structure, but i cannot see it.

Can you help me generalize the training in batch to work with any number of examples and batch size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the other answer was accepted, as there is a fundamental misunderstanding in the way you constructed the model in the question! And the other answer does not take this into account.
When you define a model and its input and output sizes, you still only consider one sample. You don't use `batch_size` for scaling the output. When you then give a batch of input data into the model, `PyTorch` handles the batch internally and the model gets evaulated on each sample in parallel.

You can look at an official [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/buildmodel_tutorial.html), where they built a model for data on the `Fashion MNIST` dataset. Each image in this dataset is `(28x28x1)` pixels (greyscale), and there are 10 different classes to predict. Notice the first and last layer:

> nn.Linear(28*28, 512)
> ....
> nn.Linear(512, 10)

where the input is the image pixels `28*28` and the output is `10` numbers for 10 classes. You can then use `SoftMax` or `categorical_crossentropy` for prediction. There is no information on batch sizes in the model itself, as the model doesn't need that.

Most of the time it is no problem to have the last batch a bit smaller than the others. If your batch size is `32`, but the last batch is only `15` samples, the model will just get 15 samples and labels, do the prediction and compare the 15 results to the 15 labels for the last batch.
If for some reason you need all batches to be exactly the same size (e.g. for a stateful `LSTM`), then you can use `DataLoader` with `drop_last=True`. But most of the time, it is not needed and you just hide data from the model if you use it.

Using the `DataLoader` is still a good idea, because they can efficiently handle loading your data on CPU, while the model will train on GPU.

Comment: Thanks! that was my mistake. I thought the batch size had to be the same size of last layer's output. Now I understand it's instead the number of classes. But because i am using it for regression i will set it to 1.

Comment: Yes, for normal regression 1 is correct as output. Also, I would not do `ReLU` on the last layer. In PyTorch, just use no activation on the last layer. In regression, you don't need it (mostly), and in classification `nn.CrossEntropy` has softmax built in.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a Pytorch `DataLoader` for loading data batch by batch instead of doing it manually. In this regard, PyTorch provides a simple solution for this using the `drop_last` parameter in the `DataLoader`. When set to True, it drops the last incomplete batch, ensuring that all batches are of the specified size except for the last one.
The `Dataloader` is a wrapper for the torch `Dataset`, you can find more info [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html)

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

X = torch.Tensor(...)  # your features
y = torch.Tensor(...)  # your labels

dataset = 

# Create a DataLoader with drop_last=True
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

model = ...

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Training loop
num_epochs = 5
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for batch_x, batch_y in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, batch_y)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    average_loss = total_loss / len(dataloader)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Average Loss: {average_loss}')
```